# vim - set relativenumber not working from vimrc, only works when set in buffer

Tags: vim, vimrc

For the life of me, I cannot figure out why `set relativenumber` does not load when set in my `.vimrc` file.  Other settings, like `set number` and setting the color scheme work perfectly.  If I want `set relativenumber`, I need to set it in the current buffer explicitly.  Any ideas?  My `.vimrc` file can be found here:

https://github.com/mhamrah/vimfiles/blob/master/.vimrc

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's because you have `:set number` later in your .vimrc -- `number` and `relativenumber` are incompatible with one another. Take out that line.

Comment: Thanks, it worked!  I had no idea they were mutually exclusive.  I thought number turned on numbering while relativenumber made it relative.

Comment: Note, this is no longer true, as of version 7.3.787. Recent versions of Vim allow you to set both options at the same time; in that case the current line number will show an absolute value, every other line will show relative values.